# Fragment with AsyncTask and Navigation Drawer - Best practice

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

I write this question because I would like to know which is the best way to manage this context: I have a MainActivity with Navigation Drawer and whenever I select an item in Navigation Drawer, I create a new fragment and through the FragmentTransaction I replace the previous fragment with the new one.

Now, in every fragment I have an AsyncTask that performs some task (eg download data from web or perform a query on a local sqlite database).

My question is: how can I avoid to recreate every time the fragment and restart AsyncTask when I press an element in Navigation Drawer? Which is the best way to manage this situation?

This is the method that I use in MainActivity to display fragment when I press an item in Navigation Drawer:

```
private void displayView(int index) {

    Fragment f = null;

    switch(index) {
        case 1:
            f = Fragment1.newInstance();
            break;
        case 2:
            f = Fragment2.newInstance();
            break;
    }

    if(f !=  null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, f);

        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `AsyncTaskLoader` instead of `AsyncTask` to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a fragment is an alternative to removing it.  Removal (if not added to the backstack) causes the fragment to be completely torn down (pause, stop, destroyView, destroy, detach).  Hiding doesn't change the fragment's lifecycle state, it just makes it not visible.  The `FragmentTransaction` methods are [hide()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide(android.app.Fragment)) and [show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show(android.app.Fragment)).  Initially, you would add both your fragments, and then hide the unselected one.  When a fragment is selected from the navigation drawer, if it is not already visible, you would hide the old selection and make the new selection visible.  Something like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .hide(oldSelectedFrag)
        .show(newSelectedFrag)
        .commit();
```

The visible/hidden status of a fragment is available using [isHidden()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isHidden()).  There is also a `Fragment` callback: [onHiddenChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean)).  Keep in mind that when a fragment is hidden it is still active in the sense of being in the started or resumed state.  You may want to use the hidden status to disable refreshes or other actions that are only needed when it is visible.  If the fragment has an option menu, you may also want disable that using [setMenuVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setMenuVisibility(boolean)) when the fragment is hidden.  I don't think the `FragmentManager` does that for you automatically.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I ask you a question: if I had many fragments or if a fragment used a lot of memory, hiding theme without replacing theme, wouldn't have a negative impact on the memory usage?

Comment: Keeping a fragment alive and hiding it does use more memory.  The amount of memory depends on how complex the fragment's UI is and the size of the data objects that support the UI and other processing.  You will need to look at the memory usage of your fragments and how many there are.  Perhaps there is some memory you could release when the fragment becomes hidden, and then re-allocate when the fragment becomes visible again.  The trade-off between responsiveness and memory usage is one you need to evaluate and decide.